# Is regular expression quite enough to handle script injection?

Tags: php

What else do you think would be a great tool to prevent form injection, URL injection, or any other kind of injection?

Not too specific to the code, just the big picture.

Comment: "Any other kind of injection"? No, there is no solve-all magic bullet for that, sorry.

Comment: A more correct solution might involve a dozen regular expressions, not just one. You're talking everything from your basic end-quote SQL injection, to you're insane bin-hexed ad-hoc SQL injection

Comment: [Have you tried logarithms?](http://xkcd.com/451/)

Comment: nope.. explain it to me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## filter your input / validate your output

That's it. For avoiding script injections, or any other kind of Cross-site Scripting, you need to ensure that any character displayed on the webpage as part of text is not any of the 5 special html characters. Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to encode them to their equivalent html entities (which are displayed normally, but not processed by the html engine):

- & becomes &amp;
- > becomes &gt;
- < becomes &lt;
- ' becomes &#039;
- " becomes &quot;

For SQL injection, the principle is the same, avoid special SQL characters in your queries, by using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string), [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysqli-real-escape-string), [`pg_escape_string`](http://php.net/pg-escape-string), [`PHP Data Objects (PDO)`](http://php.net/pdo) or prepared statements.

To avoid shell commands injection, you need to avoid another set of characters. Use [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd) and [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg).

And for other mediums, other characters are involved, and other functions needed. As someone said in a comment, there is no silver bullet.

Answer (score 2):

The big picture is best summarised by the term: Filter Input Escape Output (FIEO).

PHP has all the tools you need to perform these functions, but you need to fully grok what each of them means, identify the correct tool and apply it properly.

It might help to think of PHP as the man in the middle.

In one direction anything PHP is expected to handle, which comes from any external source should be "Filtered" against expectations where possible.

Anything PHP then passes the data to has to be Escaped so that next environment is protected from any kind of malicious attack.  Escaped so that it does not damage the database, or escaped so that it cannot cause a XSS attack if echoed onto a web page, are the two most common scenarios.

Comment: I like your 'man in the middle' analogy : )

Comment: I'd rather have "woman in the middle'.. anyway, that's a great enlightenment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All sorts of injection you are talking about (URL, SQL, Form, Headers, etc); they can all only happen when you use data retrieved from such sources without caution.

The moment you use a _GET/_POST/etc variable directly inside a SQL query, return headers or even script filenames/urls; the code is influenced by injection.

However, as long as you don't just use those variables, and always escape them correctly to make sense (e.g. mysql_real_escape_string for SQL queries), then injection isn't that easy anymore.

Using regex to validate input when used somewhere is possible too, but then the weakest link is your regular expression. You'd have to make sure to test the regular expression on practically any malicious input possible to your script.

The main thing is just to sanitize your input. Never use anything that can be changed by a user directly, ever.